# rxjs upgrade 5 to 6. Cannot find a differ supporting object '' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, observable

I am trying to upgrade Angular 5 to 6. I upgraded the `rxjs` version from 5.5.6 to 6.6.2 with `rxjs-compact` 6.6.2. without changing follwing dependencies.
[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgkP1.png)

No build issues but at run time I get following error in console:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph7fN.png)

This is the previous version of service files, this was working without any issue(rxjs 5.5.6).
[service call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yIxm.png)
[map and exception handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTtQs.png)

This is the current file.(rxjs 6.6.2). Restructured by `rxjs-compat`.
[changed service call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2jTJ.png)
[changed map and exception handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6VR2.png)

These are couple of out puts of response I got at front end.
[http response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugj8N.jpg)
[mapped response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTqhA.jpg)
Can some one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: The error is "simply" telling you that you have an ngFor over something that is not iterable, i.e. something that is not an array. The error per se is not linked to RxJS at all. Please check which ngFor is triggering the exception, and try to check what the actual value is. Maybe you just need an `async` or similar. Or the observable is throwing out an empty string or a null.

Comment: I guess you mean `rxjs-compat`, not `rxjs-compact`. The `compat` stands for `compatibility`.

Comment: Yes @MoxxiManagarm you are right. My bad.  I additionally added two images of response what I get.

Comment: @Ruwan The error clearly comes from a ngFor within any template. Can you show the ngFor and it's related object you want to iterate?

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I cannot upload images to this. So I added them as a answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot upload any more images to my question. So I added those images in this.
These are some of the images at component level.

[response at component level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXseJ.jpg)
[response item count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C91v7.jpg)

I use kendo-angular-grid to present data(refreshGridView() method).These images are relating to that.

[grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dokHY.jpg)
[grid view count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tndPT.jpg)